# Error: 'zsh: illegal hardware instruction' in C

Tags: c, strcat

I was learning `string.h` header file and wrote a simple program to concatenate two strings.

**The simple C program**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   
    char str1[] = "sandeep";
    char str2[] = "sahani";
    strcat(str1, str2);
    printf("%s %s", str1, str2);

    return 0;
}
```

Got an error which says:

> "/Users/sandeepsahani/Desktop/Sandeep Sahani/Basic Programming/ C programming/Basic Programs/DS/"stringConcat
> zsh: illegal hardware instruction

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full complete error message you get when you execute your code. Also explain in detail how you compile and run your program.

Comment: In your own words, when you write `char str1[] = "sandeep";`, how many bytes of storage do you expect to be allocated to store the data? Why? What do you expect to happen if you try to append more data to the end? Why?

Comment: String variables in C are *not* magic containers that automatically grow to hold any string you try to hold in them.  When constructing new strings — even when using library functions like `strcat` — it's *your* job to ensure that there's enough memory allocated to hold the final result.

Comment: Did you try putting for example `strcat crash` into a search engine, or looking at the documentation for `strcat`, or searching on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @SteveSummit yes sir you are correct I have tried and it worked :) thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

couple of problems here:

1. char arrays that are initialized with static data should be treated as readonly, and not updated.  You can't just add more characters to the end of it.  It may work, or may generate an error. Undefined behavior.
2. you have to allocate enough memory for the target string to hold all the concatenations.

```
int main()
{
       
    char str1[] = "sandeep";
    char str2[] = "sahani";
    char str3[100] = {0};
    
    strcat(str3, str1);
    strcat(str3, str2);    
    printf("%s %s  %s", str1, str2,str3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Char arrays are not read-only. You're thinking of `char *str1 = "sandeep";`

Comment: @Barmar you are correct sir i did that correction and that program is working :) thanks once again.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't specify the size of an array, the size is just enough to hold the values it's being initialized with. So `str1` only has 8 characters (7 characters plus the null terminator). That's not enough room to add `sandeep` to it.

If you want to concatenate to it, you need it to have room for the additional string. Since `str2` is 6 characters, `str1` needs at least 14 characters. So change it to:

```
char str1[14] = "sandeep";
```

Comment: @LtWorf first off, that marker *doesn't indicate correctness* (it indicates *acceptance* by OP), and second you have done nothing to explain what you find wrong with this answer.

Comment: @LtWorf He accepted that answer before I posted mine.